# how to set body for mock of ServiceBusReceivedMessage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to create `mock` for `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` with the body. How to do it?

I have `data` variable which I want to set as message body, how to do it?

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData));

var message = new Mock<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>().Object;
        
//message.Body;
```

I tried below code, compile no error, but while running giving error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Body
> Non-overridable members (here: ServiceBusReceivedMessage.get_Body) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

```
var mockMessage = new Mock<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>();
var messageBody = new BinaryData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData)));
mockMessage.Setup(x => x.Body).Returns(new BinaryData(messageBody));
var message = mockMessage.Object;
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: With moq you can mock only `virtual` or `abstract` fields or properties.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to create an instance of a class with specific data in it, for which I would recommend to use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) from [Nuget store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/autofixture/)

Example:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var messageBody = new BinaryData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData)));
var mockedServiceBusReceivedMessage = fixture
    .Build<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>()
    .With(e => e.Body, messageBody)
    .Create();
```

If you want to avoid generating automatic data for other properties, add `.OmitAutoProperties()` before `.Create()`.

If you want to use `Moq` for `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`, first you should create an interface for your class:

```
public interface IServiceBusReceivedMessage
{
    BinaryData Body { get; }
}
```

And then substitute your class to this interface:

```
public class ServiceBusReceivedMessage : IServiceBusReceivedMessage
{
    BinaryData Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use `IServiceBusReceivedMessage` to setup mocked response for `Body` as in your example, but I doubt that you need to construct `BinaryData` from `BinaryData`, so it would probably be:

```
var mockMessage = new Mock<IServiceBusReceivedMessage>();
var messageBody = new BinaryData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData)));
mockMessage.Setup(x => x.Body).Returns(messageBody);
var message = mockMessage.Object;
```

And maybe I'm stating obvious here, but still will note this down:
Everywhere where there's `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` parameter, it should be changed to `IServiceBusReceivedMessage` for this new mocked object to be accepted.